# Make checkBox read only

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I want to have a read-Only checkbox and disable the toggle( checked /unchecked) when I click the checkbox. Which possiblities I have? This is my code:

```
<label className="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</label>
```

I read a post where this workaround is proposed:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" />
```

...but how can I use it in React?

Comment: i'm not huge on react but have you tried setting the disabled attribute? ie <input type="checkbox" disabled/>

Comment: Yes, I tried it this way --> disabled={true} .. But I don´t want to change the style and hoped for a possiblity where I can only disable the click-function

Comment: There's a difference between your title and your question content. If you want to disable the box (clicking on it does nothing - set `disabled` to `true`) you can't then toggle the checked states _because_ it's disabled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have this variable to control if the checkbox is enabled/disabled

```
const [isCheckboxDisabled, setCheckboxDisabled] = useState(false);
```

You can disable the checkbox by means of the `disabled` attribute like:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled={isCheckboxDisabled} />
```

Or with the workaround you found

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="onCheckboxClick" />

function onCheckboxClick(e) {
   if (this.isCheckboxDisabled) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
}
```

*I would suggest the first strategy, as is ARIA compliant, and changes the input styles so it is visibly disabled.*

Comment: I  changed the function because I want to have it never clickable and it works:

function onCheckboxClick(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
    }

Comment: @Davidbo123321 - Nice, or simply do `<input type="checkbox" disabled />` this will also disable it. If you believe the answer to be correct remember to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make this checkbox disabled forever you just need to add disabled attribute like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled onclick="return false"/>
```

but if you want to have control of this disabled attribute you should create a new boolean state by useState() and then just pass value to disabled attribute like that:

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

return (
<input type="checkbox" disabled={isDisabled} onclick="return false"/>
)
```